# Redshift: Using DATE_TRUNC makes duplicated rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

`SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', "date") as dates FROM dim_calendar dc WHERE "date" > '2019-01-01' AND "date" < CURRENT_DATE` 
is creating duplicates.

Example of outcome seen:

| A header |
| --- |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-14 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-14 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-14 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-14 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-14 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-14 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-14 |

Expected Result:

| A header |
| --- |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-14 00:00:00 |

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have several dates per week. You can add `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('week', "date") as dates FROM dim_calendar dc WHERE "date" > '2019-01-01' AND "date" < CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Is there another way to solve this without the use of DISTINCT ?

Comment: Try adding `GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week', "date")` to the end

Comment: `group by` [groups together rows with non-distinct values](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause)